# Create A Random Matrix With Numbers From (-1,1)

Tags: matlab

the function : `Rand(n)`  starts from 1 and `Randi(iMin,iMax)` does not use al real numbers from -1 to 1, just -1,0,1 is there a function that does it?

Comment: `rand(n)*2 - 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can always scale and shift the [0,1] range:

```
2*rand(n)-1;
```

Comment: Assigning intellectual weight to 'immaterial' is unintelligent (among other things); I had no such intention. I'm assuming you're not using the mobile app so you're not familiar with the lack of such a feature there.

Comment: I made no assumptions about your intentions; I was just making a suggestion and providing some guidance. I hope it is welcomed. Apologies for sounding like an accusation. BTW, I do use the app, but I didn't know you were.

Comment: Note that I would have just downvoted has I thought your intentions were in any way contemptible, no matter how petty. On the contrary, it's great that you provided an answer! I certainly don't want to discourage constructive participation like this.

Comment: I appreciate that; and I didn't mean any offense -at all. I apologize  for the other impression you might have picked. And to be honest, I'm not much of a 'society/class/rank/etc' person, so the up and downs are more of a game to me -despite the fact that I truly appreciate your good intentions. Have a great day :-)

Comment: But it's such a fun game!  :)

Comment: Actually it's just a 'game', which is a subclass of 'fun' -something that is not inherently productive. :-)

Comment: No argument here. SO is a time-waster, make no mistake. However, it does have the side effect of creating (potentially) useful information to third parties.

Comment: I am actually here for 'getting started' on Matlab. I am taking the scattered approach as my priorities lie elsewhere. For example few minutes ago I was reading your answer to 'Error running Matlab code after compiling' and I learned something of a potential branch that I might later decide to expand upon if the need presents itself.

Answer (score 0):

use matlab's `randsample()` function:

```
replacement = true; N = 10; 
 v = randsample([1,-1],N,replacement)
```

this produces a (1xN) vector v with random (-1,1) entries. To turn v into a matrix use `reshape()`, e.g.

```
 m = reshape(v,2,5)
```